# icons is grayed in c# program

Tags: c#, imagelist

i use some png icons in my program written in c#.
i have a very strange problem with them. the color of the icons get to be grayed over time and with run program. in below picture the picture at the first inserted (right image) and after the about 200 times program run (left image) is shown.
[image]
whats your idea? where this problem is coming from? how can i prevent this effect?

Comment: Please tell exactly what you do with the icon. Apparently, the application changes the icon in a way that you expect it not to change at all (and the change is invisible to the naked eye) but the repeated application of that change leads to this effect.

Comment: the icon that i have showed is not changed at all and only it displayes in program. this is not button or else component.. i use it from an image list in the dev express navigation bar.

Comment: May be your program is being used on touch devices, so it may be rubbed hardly

Comment: no. it is used in non-touch laptop.

Comment: Does the same change happen to the icon file? or is it only visible in the Application? How can you revert the icon to the original state? by restarting the application? Closing the form? Reinstalling the app? recompiling? or Do you have to replace the icon file with the original one?

Comment: only replacing the icon from the source can restore the icon appearance